# I'm having trouble making a function to tell me how many earthquakes occur in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

For my CompSci homework, I was given a CSV file and am supposed to create code to print the number of earthquakes reported in the file. The first line of the CSV is a header, followed by 13 lines of data. Therefore, I know there are 13 earthquakes. My trouble is that in line seven I keep getting an index out of range error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Thonny\Files\march25.py", line 7, in <module>
    while lineBeingRead[disasterType] != "earthquake":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the CSV file

```
time,latitude,longitude,depth,mag,magType,nst,gap,dmin,rms,net,id,updated,place,type,horizontalError,depthError,magError,magNst,status,locationSource,magSource
2020-03-23T01:17:15.310Z,40.779,-112.053,9.98,3.94,ml,44,52,0.01894,0.19,uu,uu60369062,2020-03-24T22:26:20.015Z,"8km NNE of Magna, Utah",earthquake,0.28,0.44,0.205,20,reviewed,uu,uu
2020-03-22T05:24:03.828Z,45.8972,15.9662,10,5.4,mww,,13,0.802,0.8,us,us70008dx7,2020-03-24T23:09:37.745Z,"3km SW of Kasina, Croatia",earthquake,4.6,1.8,0.052,35,reviewed,us,us
2020-03-21T01:33:35.369Z,39.1112,-119.7361,8.4,4.5,ml,31,28.07,0.029,0.1334,nn,nn00719663,2020-03-24T21:50:29.491Z,"6km N of Johnson Lane, Nevada",earthquake,,1.2,0.38,5,reviewed,nn,nn
2020-03-20T01:33:15.377Z,28.6065,87.3298,10,5.7,mww,,30,0.79,0.89,us,us70008cld,2020-03-24T16:06:24.685Z,"24km E of Xegar, China",earthquake,6.5,1.7,0.063,24,reviewed,us,us
2020-03-18T22:08:20.920Z,40.3475,-124.4561667,28.61,5.21,mw,34,248,0.105,0.16,nc,nc73355700,2020-03-24T22:18:27.177Z,"15km W of Petrolia, CA",earthquake,0.78,0.55,,5,reviewed,nc,nc
2020-03-18T19:12:23.610Z,40.751,-112.059,10.65,4.57,mw,39,47,0.02976,0.21,uu,uu60364832,2020-03-24T22:25:19.766Z,"5km NE of Magna, Utah",earthquake,0.32,0.53,,12,reviewed,uu,uu
2020-03-18T17:45:38.838Z,-11.0591,115.131,17.59,6.2,mww,,24,2.747,1.06,us,us60008hzl,2020-03-21T16:28:15.002Z,"246km S of Kangin, Indonesia",earthquake,7.2,3,0.038,65,reviewed,us,us
2020-03-18T14:02:12.830Z,40.7605,-112.0693333,9.07,4.59,mw,21,58,0.03587,0.19,uu,uu60363822,2020-03-24T22:24:20.649Z,"7km NNE of Magna, Utah",earthquake,0.39,0.8,,17,reviewed,uu,uu
2020-03-18T13:09:31.530Z,40.751,-112.0783333,11.9,5.7,mw,54,50,0.04022,0.2,uu,uu60363602,2020-03-25T00:28:33.745Z,"6km NNE of Magna, Utah",earthquake,0.3,0.39,,0,reviewed,uu,uu
2020-03-14T10:01:17.383Z,-27.4196,-175.6847,10,6.3,mww,,22,2.687,1.03,us,us60008fl8,2020-03-15T10:03:53.243Z,"298km NE of Raoul Island, New Zealand",earthquake,7.6,1.8,0.063,24,reviewed,us,us
2020-03-11T01:17:16.090Z,39.4751667,-120.2455,7.87,3.71,mw,16,70,0.1363,0.07,nc,nc73352615,2020-03-21T15:21:43.839Z,"17km NNW of Truckee, CA",earthquake,0.28,0.91,,4,reviewed,nc,nc
2020-03-09T02:59:08.860Z,40.3916667,-125.0936667,3.19,5.77,mw,40,277,0.5832,0.29,nc,nc73351710,2020-03-22T20:17:55.040Z,"69km W of Petrolia, CA",earthquake,0.99,1.38,,4,reviewed,nc,nc
2020-03-07T03:52:03.180Z,31.6893333,-114.5405,9.98,5.49,mw,13,106,0.3208,0.35,ci,ci38385946,2020-03-22T03:11:14.628Z,"71km SE of Estacion Coahuila, B.C., MX",earthquake,0.78,31.61,,6,reviewed,ci,ci
```

Here's my code(note: not complete yet)

```
import csv
with open("earthquakes.csv", "r") as inFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(inFile)
    lineBeingRead = next(csvReader)
    earthquakes = 0 #will be used for the final print value
    column = 0 #each line has a value called type, which is referred to as earthquake
    while lineBeingRead[column] != "earthquake": 
        column = column + 1
        if column == "earthquake":
            lineBeingRead = next(csvReader)
            earthquakes = earthquakes
        #else
        #print
```

My main question is why am I getting this error and what can I do to fix it. Secondly, how would I go about implementing an if / else statement in my while loop. I want to say if that column has an earthquake, add it to the total number of earthquakes and move onto the next line. if not, add one to column and try again.

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: What does your csv file looks like? Can you provide a sample?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Just made those changes

Comment: @ShubhamSharma just made those changes!

Comment: The problem is that your loop doesn't know when you're at the end of the file, so when it reads the last line it just keeps going and calls `next()` again, resulting in an empty list, and that is where the error happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try with [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) from `csv` module:

```
earthquakes = 0
with open('earthquakes.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for dct in reader:
        if dct['type'].lower() == 'earthquake':
            earthquakes += 1
```

---

```
>>> earthquakes

13
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't even think about this. I was a bit fixated on doing it using what we just learned about CSV files and interacting with them that I forgot I could use those functions which we learned months ago :D

Comment: Hmmm.. not sure if I would accept this as correct if I were the teacher. Obviously the column `type` should be checked for the exact string "earthquake". What if it contained "not an earthquake", or extra data was later added to updates of the csv file (maybe a column containing a reference to an "earthquake map" in a row that is not an earthquake). Anyway, if there's no check on the type column, maybe at least check for `",earthquake,"`. (I don't know Python, so I can't provide a solution myself)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma  A+ now! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
print(sum("earthquake" in line
      for line in open("earthquakes.csv", "r"))
```

This will open the file, iterate through the lines, and return `True` or `False` according to whether "earthquake" is in that line.  `sum`ming that series treats `True` as 1, and `False` as 0.  In short, a count of how many lines contain "earthquake".